# The function f:(0, 1)→R defined by f(x) = x is a homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis

Would this make sense?

Since f is continuous, then for any open interval (a, b) in R, the pre-image f^(-1)(a,b) is the open interval (a b) intersected with (0,1), which is also an open interval.

Furthermore, the inverse function f^(-1):R→(0, 1) defined by f^(-1)(y) = y is also continuous, since for any open interval (a, b) in (0, 1), f((a,b)) = (a,b) and for any open interval (c, d) in R, where f^(-1)((c, d)) = (c, d).

Therefore, f is a homeomorphism between (0, 1) and R.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Specifically, what goes wrong in what you've written is that "$f^{-1}$" is not a function from $\Bbb R$ to $(0, 1)$ because eg it sends $2$ to $2$, which isn't in $(0, 1)$ (I would say it fails to be well-defined, or it has the wrong range). Remember that homeomorphisms have to be bijections!

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I missed that